# How can I prevent widgets from overlapping?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How to resolve widget overlapping in kivy framework, I am adding widgets in for cycle so I have more than one widget but all of them comes to be in one place, how can I prevent this?

My python code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import requests, time, collections

class request_sender():
    return 'DATA'

class CustomLabel(Label):
    pass
class CustomBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class AuctionCard(Widget):
    auc_timer = ''
    auc_img = ''
    auc_name = ''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AuctionCard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before: Color(1, 0, .4, mode='rgb')
        Clock.schedule_once(self.load_info)

    def load_info(self, dt):
        print(self.auc_name)
        self.size_hint = None, None
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size = (800, 600))
        box.size_hint_x = 50;
        box.height = 100
        AuctionName = CustomLabel(text=self.auc_name, pos_hint={'top': 300.9})
        AuctionImage = CustomLabel(text=self.auc_img)
        AuctionTimer = CustomLabel(text=self.auc_name)
        box.add_widget(AuctionName)
        box.add_widget(AuctionTimer)
        box.add_widget(AuctionImage)
        self.add_widget(box)

class MyWidget(Widget):
    prop = StringProperty('')
    array_of_labels = []
    prop1 = StringProperty('Second card')
    n = 0
    all_cards = collections.defaultdict()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen_load()
    def timer_le(self, dt):
        returned_data = request_sender().sender_update('ajax.php')
        for key in self.all_cards:
            for data in returned_data:
                if data['pid'] == key:
                    self.all_cards[key][0].text = str(data['remaining_time'])

    def screen_load(self):
        returned_data = request_sender().sender_update('ajax.php')
        box = GridLayout(cols=2)
        self.size_hint = None, None
        for data in returned_data:
            AucCard = AuctionCard()
            AucCard.auc_name = str(data['auc_name'])+'\n\n'
            AucCard.auc_timer = str(data['remaining_time'])+'\n\n'
            AucCard.auc_img = str(data['auc_img'])+'\n\n'
            box.add_widget(AucCard)
            print('Widget added')
        self.add_widget(box)
            #self.all_cards[str(data['pid'])] = [AucCard]
        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.timer_le, 1/30)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        box = GridLayout(cols=2)
        return MyWidget()

TestApp().run()
```

My kv code:

```
<CustomLabel>:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Result:

[image]

Kind of result that I want to create:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found easy way to solve this issue. The problem was in parent class of my AuctionCard and MyWidget classes, I set parent class to Widget but for the AuctionCard it should be BoxLayout and for MyWidget GridLayout. So from there I managed to set cols = 2 and size to window.size. From here it works exactly how it should work.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class AuctionCard(BoxLayout):
    auc_timer = ''
    auc_img = ''
    auc_name = ''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AuctionCard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.load_info)
    def load_info(self, dt):
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        AuctionName = Label(text=self.auc_name)
        AuctionImage = Label(text=self.auc_img)
        AuctionTimer = Label(text=self.auc_timer)
        self.add_widget(AuctionName)
        self.add_widget(AuctionTimer)
        self.add_widget(AuctionImage)

class MyWidget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.size = (Window.size[0], self.size[1])
        self.load_app()
        print('MyWidget size: '+str(self.size))
    def load_app(self):
        self.size_hint = None, None
        returned_data = [{'auc_name':'name 1', 'remaining_time':'100', 'auc_img':'https://img.src'},
                         {'auc_name':'name 2', 'remaining_time':'200', 'auc_img':'https://img.src'},
                         {'auc_name':'name 3', 'remaining_time':'300', 'auc_img':'https://img.src'}]
        for data in returned_data:
            AucCard = AuctionCard()
            AucCard.auc_name = str(data['auc_name'])+'\n\n'
            AucCard.auc_timer = str(data['remaining_time'])+'\n\n'
            AucCard.auc_img = str(data['auc_img'])+'\n\n'
            self.add_widget(AucCard)
            print('Widget added')


class MyTestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "My Material Application"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyTestApp().run()
```

Result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJC1S.png)